# Is there a way in Google sheets to emulate MATCH using ARRAYFORMULA and VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As you may know, in Sheets the function `match` returns the position of a found value within a range. But to find several values we need to `Ctrl+D` downwards the entire column.

I was wondering whether there is a way to achieve the same results but by placing just one formula at the top row and including `Arrayformula` and `vlookup` or with any other function that returns the position of the value in the range.
That's all.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Use `BYROW()` or `MAP()` function to make any formula as dynamic spill array formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Never used ```byrow``` and ```map()```. If we would like to lookup range A:A into ranbe B:B, what would be the formula? Thanks

Comment: Can you please share a sample google-sheet here so that we can put formula to that sheet. Show your input and then desired output.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Basically match works within arrayformula so there's no need to use byrow and map. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`Match` works with `arrayformula`, so no need to use `vlookup`.